# How to denote adjacent vertices?

Tags: math-mode, graphs, inline, strikeout

#### Background

I'm trying to write a rapport that relies on some rudimentary graph theory and as
such I'd like to write a section explaining the basics of it.

#### Trying to do

I've run into a bit of a snag trying to adequately write out pairs of
vertices that have an edge between them. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable
in regards to TeX either knows of the command which I seek or of a way to create it:

I mean to write vertices `u` and `v` (in math-mode) with a long line between them,
approximately the distance of an em-dash. This line denotes an edge between the vertices. However I need to be able to also denote the lack of such an edge by
being able to strike over said line (\not). Any and all help would be much
appreciated!

#### Tested

I've tried

```
$u \not\textemdash v$
```

and

```
$u \not\textrm{---} v$
$u \not\textrm{\textemdash} v$
```

however neither works. The latter two are close but I'd need to be able to move the
symbol generated by `\not` to the right by about half an em somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\arrownot` from `stmaryrd`; the normal `\not` seems too big for a simple bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for \arrownot
\newcommand{\notedge}{%
  \mathrel{\mkern-2mu}% a small back up
  \arrownot % a short slash
  \mathrel{\mkern2mu}% compensate
  \mathrel{-}% minus as a relation
}

\begin{document}
$u\notedge v$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This exploits two facts: `\arrownot` has zero width and is classified as a relation symbol (it extends past its bounding box); TeX doesn't add space between consecutive relation symbols (which can also be spaces)

This is how `$u\not\mathrel{-}v$` would print:

[image]

A possible alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}

\newcommand{\notedge}{\centernot{\mathrel{-}\joinrel\mathrel{-}}}

\begin{document}

$u\notedge v$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another proposal with longer symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for \arrownot

\newcommand{\edge}{%
  \mathrel{-}% minus as a relation
  \joinrel\joinrel % some backup
  \mathrel{-}% minus as a relation
}
\newcommand{\notedge}{%
  \mathrel{\mkern2mu}% a small advancement
  \arrownot % a short slash
  \mathrel{\mkern-2mu}% compensate
  \edge
}

\begin{document}

$u \edge v$

$u\notedge v$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) provides centering of `\not` across lengthier symbols:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot
\newcommand{\adjacent}[1][.7em]{\mathrel{\rule[.5ex]{#1}{.4pt}}}
\newcommand{\notadjacent}[1][.7em]{\mathrel{\centernot{\adjacent[#1]}}}
\begin{document}
$u \adjacent v \notadjacent w \adjacent[1em] x \notadjacent[1em] y$
\end{document}
```

Both `\adjacent[<len>]` and `\nonadjacent[<len>]` take an optional argument with the defauly being `.7em`.

Comment: This is, like the above, an excellent answer. Unfortunately I'm new on TeX.sx and cannot give you the vote up that you deserve. But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is late, but I made these symbols that I use to differentiate between undirected, directed, and their weighted counterparts.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ue}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\draw[fill = black] (.25ex,.25ex) circle (.3ex);
\draw[thick] (.55ex,.25ex) -- (1.55ex,.25ex);%
\draw[fill = black] (1.85ex, .25ex) circle (.3ex);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\newcommand{\de}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\draw[fill = black] (.25ex,.25ex) circle (.3ex);
\draw[thick, ->] (.55ex,.25ex) -- (1.85ex,.25ex);%

\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```